# Where can I found the installation package of Dell's OEM Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, oem

1. Does Dell's OEM WindoWindows 7 installed some customized softwares?
2. Where can I found the installation package of these customized software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dell ships two CD/DVDs with each computer, one is a standard OEM installation DVD, the other is a driver and application disc. If you have removed the recovery partition you can restore your Dell to a near-factory state by installing Windows 7 from the OEM DVD and then installing the extra software from the software DVD.

You can also find drivers etc on Dell's support site.